# How to generate view from multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created view by following queries, but while selecting data from this view it generates multiple rows for same students I mean it has to generates data depending on [studentsledger] table not from currentacademicinformation table because if 1 students had passed 1 class and currently if he is reading in 2 class then it generates 2 rows it should not be because studentledger is the table where students paid bill is stored??

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[StudentLedgerView] 
AS
   SELECT     
       dbo.StudentsLedger.StudentLedgerId, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.FiscalYearId, 
       dbo.FiscalYears.FiscalYearName, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.AcademicSessionId, 
       dbo.AcademicSessions.Name,
       dbo.StudentsLedger.StudentId, 
       dbo.StudentPersonalInformations.CodeNumber,
       dbo.StudentPersonalInformations.FirstName + ' ' + dbo.StudentPersonalInformations.MiddleName + ' ' + dbo.StudentPersonalInformations.LastName AS StudentName,
       dbo.StudentsLedger.SystemEntryDate, dbo.StudentsLedger.DateAD, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.DateBS, dbo.StudentsLedger.ReceiptNumber, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.ReceiptGeneratedBy, 
       dbo.UserDetails.Name AS ReceiptPreparedBy, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.ReceivedAmount, dbo.StudentsLedger.ReturnAmount, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.TotalAmount, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.TotalDiscount, dbo.StudentsLedger.TotalFine, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.TotalAdjustedFine, 
       dbo.StudentsLedger.IsCancelled,
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.StudentLedgerDetailId, 
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.FeeSetupId, 
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.Particulars, 
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.Amount, 
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.TaxAmount,                        
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.AdjustedAmount, 
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.MonthName, dbo.LevelsName.LevelName, 
       dbo.Classes.ClassName, 
       dbo.Faculties.FacultyName, dbo.Programs.ProgramFullName, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.Section, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.RollNumber, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.LevelNameId, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.ProgramId, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.YearSem, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.ClassId, 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.FacultyId
   FROM         
       dbo.StudentsLedger 
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.AcademicSessions ON dbo.StudentsLedger.AcademicSessionId = dbo.AcademicSessions.AcademicSessionId  
   LEFT JOIN
       dbo.FiscalYears ON dbo.StudentsLedger.FiscalYearId = dbo.FiscalYears.FiscalYearId 
   LEFT JOIN 
       dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails ON dbo.StudentsLedger.StudentLedgerId = dbo.StudentsLedgerDetails.StudentLedgerId 
   LEFT JOIN 
       dbo.StudentPersonalInformations ON dbo.StudentsLedger.StudentId = dbo.StudentPersonalInformations.StudentPersonalInformationId 
   LEFT JOIN 
       dbo.UsersInfo ON dbo.StudentsLedger.ReceiptGeneratedBy = dbo.UsersInfo.UserId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.UserDetails ON dbo.UsersInfo.UserId = dbo.UserDetails.UserId 
   LEFT JOIN 
       dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations ON dbo.StudentPersonalInformations.StudentPersonalInformationId = dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.StudentId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.LevelsName ON dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.LevelNameId = dbo.LevelsName.LevelNameId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Classes ON dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.ClassId = dbo.Classes.ClassId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Faculties ON dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.FacultyId = dbo.Faculties.FacultyId 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.Programs ON dbo.CurrentAcademicInformations.ProgramId = dbo.Programs.ProgramId AND dbo.Faculties.FacultyId = dbo.Programs.FacultyId
GO
```

Comment: you can use `DISTINCT` just after the select

Comment: Your query is returning some data from `CurrentAcademicInformations`. If, as you say, that table contains two or more rows per student, you need to decide which row you want to return. We can't decide that for you.